# Ada: Writing to files within a block statement

Tags: file, ada, declare

I am dealing with an array whose length is determined during the execution of the program. So I am making use of a `block` statement in which I can set the limits of the array.

I am having problems to write the elements of the array to a file **as I was using a stub for the write procedure**. I removed the stub to have everything in the same code. Though now my code *compiles and run*, it is not writing to the file. Here is the code:

```
with Ada.Float_Text_IO;
with Ada.Integer_Text_IO;
with Ada.Text_IO; 


procedure Compute_Parameters is

Spin_Speed, Whirling_Speed        : Float;
Time_Step, Rotor_Revolutions      : Float;
Number_Of_Steps                   : Float;


begin
Ada.Text_IO.Put("Enter the spin speed ");
Ada.Float_Text_IO.Get (Item => Spin_Speed);
Ada.Text_IO.New_Line (1);
Ada.Text_IO.Put("Enter the whirling speed ");
Ada.Float_Text_IO.Get (Item => Whirling_Speed);
Ada.Text_IO.New_Line (1);
Ada.Text_IO.Put("Enter the time step ");
Ada.Float_Text_IO.Get (Item => Time_Step);
Ada.Text_IO.New_Line (1);
Ada.Text_IO.Put("Enter the number of revolutions of the rotor ");
Ada.Float_Text_IO.Get (Item => Rotor_Revolutions);


Number_Of_Steps := (360.0 / (Time_Step * Whirling_Speed)) * Rotor_Revolutions *  (Whirling_Speed / Spin_Speed);


declare

   type Vector is array (Integer range <>) of Float;
   Time_Vector                     : Vector (1 .. Integer (Float'Truncation (Number_Of_Steps)) + 1);
   Rotor_Position_Degrees          : Vector (1 .. Integer (Float'Truncation (Number_Of_Steps)) + 1);

   Count       : Integer := 0;
   Start       : Float := 0.0;
   Step        : Float := Time_Step;

   Output_Data_File                            : File_Type;

   procedure Write_Files (Output_File          : File_Type;
                          Out_1                   : Integer;
                          Out_2                   : Float;
                          Prec                    : Natural := 5
                          ) is 
   begin
      Ada.Integer_Text_IO.Put (File => Output_File, Item => Out_1);
      Ada.Text_IO.Put (Output_File, "   ");
      Ada.Float_Text_IO.Put (File => Output_File, Item => Out_2, Fore => 6, Aft => Prec, Exp => 0);
      Ada.Text_IO.New_Line (Output_File);
   end Write_Files;



 begin -- begin of Declare

     Ada.Text_IO.Put ("Put file name to write: ");
     Create (Output_Data_File, Out_File, Get_Line);


     for I in 1 .. Time_Vector'Length  loop
         Count := Count + 1;
         Time_Vector(I) := Start + Step * Float(I-1);
         Put (Integer'Image(Count));
         Ada.Text_IO.Put("   ");
         Rotor_Position_Degrees(I) := Spin_Speed * Time_Step * Float(I-1);
         Ada.Float_Text_IO.Put (Item => Rotor_Position_Degrees(I), Fore => 5, Aft  => 1, Exp  => 0);
         Ada.Text_IO.New_Line(1);

         --write to file
         Write_Files (Output_Data_File,
                      Out_1 => Count,
                      Out_2 => Rotor_Position_Degrees(I)
                      );
     end loop;

 close(Output_Data_File);


 end; -- end of Declare


end Compute_Parameters;
```

I notice that the 2 lines just after `begin` in `Declare` are not being executed at all:

```
Ada.Text_IO.Put ("Put file name to write: ");
Create (Output_Data_File, Out_File, Get_Line);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks...

Comment: why do you write `use Ada.Text_IO;` but later you use the full package name `Ada.Text_IO.Put("Enter the spin speed ");` ? This makes little sense. Choose one or the other. If you want to use fully qualifed name, then do not do the `use` part.

Comment: @ Robert Yes I know. A slip of mine. Thanks for telling. Post edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pressing return after your last `Get` for `Rotor_Revolutions` has left an empty line in standard input, which remains to be read:

```
 Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line (Ada.Text_IO.Get_Line);
 Ada.Text_IO.Put ("Put file name to write: ");
 Create (Output_Data_File, Out_File, Ada.Text_IO.Get_Line);
```

Just to clarify: It's the `Get_Line` that's required; the `Put_Line` is just to show that it's an empty line.

Alternatively, use [`Ada.Command_Line`](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-15.html), as shown in this [example](https://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/hexdump).

Comment: I don't think the `declare` block is relevant, except that it separates the source and effect.

Comment: @ trashgod. Wow. Thanks a lot for the tip about `Put_Line`. 1 vote up

Comment: @ trashgod How to get the limit for the array length then during computation if no `declare` block is to be used?

Comment: Ok I need to look a little at `Put_Line` and `Get_Line`.

Comment: A `declare` block is a perfectly valid way to enter a nested scope. I may be overlooking something in this example, but I don't see the need for `Vector` at all; the output is constructed one row at a time.

Comment: @ trashgod Yes surely. You are right. As I am writing into files directly, I do not need any `Vector` as such. Thanks for this remark.