# dynamic array size determined at runtime in ada

Tags: ada, dynamic-arrays

Is it possible to have an array with size that is determined at runtime like so,

```
Procedure prog is
   type myArray is array(Integer range <>) of Float;
   arraySize : Integer := 0;
   theArray : myArray(0..arraySize);
Begin
   -- Get Array size from user.
   put_line("How big would you like the array?");
   get(arraySize);

   For I in 0..arraySize Loop
      theArray(I) := 1.2 * I;
   End Loop;
End prog;
```

Is there a way to achieve this result other than using dynamically Linked Lists or another similar structure? Or is there a simple built in data structure that would be simpler than using dynamically linked lists?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure, declare it in a block as follows:

```
procedure prog is
   arraySize : Integer := 0;
   type myArray is array(Integer range <>) of Float;
begin
   -- Get Array size from user.
   put_line("How big would you like the array?");
   get(arraySize);

   declare
      theArray : myArray(0..arraySize);
   begin
      for I in 0..arraySize Loop
         theArray(I) := 1.2 * I;
      end Loop;
   end;
end prog;
```

or pass the arraySize as an argument into a subprogram and declare and operate on it in that subprogram:

```
procedure Process_Array (arraySize : Integer) is

    theArray : myArray(0..arraySize);

begin
   for I in arraySize'Range Loop
      theArray(I) := 1.2 * I;
   end Loop;
end;
```

This is just illustrative (and not compiled :-), as you need to deal with things like an invalid array size and such.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was completely oblivious that you could do such a thing. Though It makes a lot of sense since that's basically what you do with functions and programs haha.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can defer the declaration of a constrained object until you know the size. In this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12923999/230513), the array `Candidates` can be allocated in a nested block (introduced by the keyword `declare`) or on the heap (using the keyword `new`). In this related [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13655744/230513), `Line` has a different size each time through the loop, depending on what `Get_Line` finds.