# How to create a dynamically allocated array in Ada?

Tags: ada

As the questions says, I want to create a dynamically allocated array in Ada. Something like C++ `std::vector` ie., I don't want to store the length of the array in a separate variable like it is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13735274/dynamic-array-size-determined-at-runtime-in-ada). As Ada supports generics, is it possible to create a `std::vector` like functionality in Ada?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Standard Libraries includes `Ada.Containers.Vectors` ([RM A.18.2](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-18-2.html))