# Ada thread to pass auto random generated data to a procedure

Tags: random, ada

How would i go about creating a procedure that is a thread which continuously passes automatic random generated data within a specified range.

I currently would have to manually enter in each bit of data in the console using this procedure below. I want to creatre a procedure that when running is able to pass data to this procedure as if it was being typed into the console itself.

```
procedure Analyse_Data is
  Data : Integer;
begin
  DT_Put_Line("Data input by user");
  loop
     DT_Get(Data,"Data must be taken as a whole number");
     exit when (Data >=0) and (Data <= Maximum_Data_Possible);
     DT_Put("Please input a value between 0 and ");
     DT_Put(Maximum_Data_Possible);
     DT_Put_Line("");
  end loop;
  Status_System.Data_Measured := Data_Range(Data);
end Analyse_Data;
```

I havent included the specification files (.ads) 
I am new to Ada and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do the `DT_` subprograms do different from the ordinary `Ada.Text_IO`? Why does it have to be a task (the Ada word for “thread”) calling this procedure instead of having something repeatedly update `Status_System.Data_Measured` directly?

Comment: I guess what I am trying to do is this: The program asks for data, ie. What is the height? (task passes some random number from a specified range) and continues asking about other variables, What is the speed? etc etc . I have it set so that these are manually input by a user but it would be better if they were done by a task instead. almost like the program is asking a set of questions and the task is just passing data back to it. Its all for research right now

Comment: If you know what order the questions are in, [trashgod’s answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36908240/40851) should do the trick. But if not, you could look at [this article about GNAT.Expect](http://www.adacore.com/adaanswers/gems/gem-54/).

Answer (score 1):

Use an instance of [`Discrete_Random`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-A-5-2.html) to generate some number of random data values in the desired range:

```
subtype Valid_Range is Natural range 0 .. Maximum_Data_Possible;
package Some_Value is new Ada.Numerics.Discrete_Random(Valid_Range);
G : Some_Value.Generator;
…
procedure Generate is
N : Valid_Range;
begin
   for I in 1 .. Count loop
      N := Some_Value.Random(G);
      Put(N);
   end loop;
end;
```

Save the values to a file:

```
./generate > test_data.txt
```

Feed that file to your program using I/O redirection from the command line:

```
./analyse_data < test_data.txt
```

The exact details will depend on you actual program. See this related [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10470664/230513) regarding empty lines in standard input.